# Dock=>Fill a control in FlowLayoutPanel

Tags: .net, user-controls

I have a UserControl in which a FlowLayoutPanel (FlowDirection is as by default - LeftToRight). 
This user control consist of a description and some controls: 
`[descr.] 123456789`, it should be able to be reversed `987654321 [descr.]`

So FlowLayoutPanel is used for this scope(RightToLeft - True/False).

[alt text http://lh5.ggpht.com/_1TPOP7DzY1E/S9B3MUrHo4I/AAAAAAAADLU/YiiSOPSQuso/s800/Capture1.png](http://lh5.ggpht.com/_1TPOP7DzY1E/S9B3MUrHo4I/AAAAAAAADLU/YiiSOPSQuso/s800/Capture1.png)

**Is this a way that the label1 fill the rest of the control(to left or right respectively)?**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unfortunately `FlowLayoutPanel` doesn't support that kind of behavior.

There are three options I know of:

1. Manually make the label take up the rest of the space. (Recalculating when the `FlowLayoutPanel` changes size.)  This is complex, especially if you add controls at runtime.
2. Use `TableLayoutPanel` instead.  It does not have 'flow' characteristics, but it does support the 'fill' behavior you want.
3. Write your own control which does this.  This could get complex.

I would probably go with the `TableLayoutPanel`, but depending on your circumstances one of the other options may make more sense.

Comment: hope that in a TableLaoytPanel reversing elements should not be too complicated.